# Have 2 hibernate.properties files

Tags: database, hibernate, testing, junit, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot project with Hibernate. I would like to use 2 separate hibernate.properties files: one for normal use of application, another only for test.

So, how can I do that? Or maybe it is not possible? I don't want to comment/uncomment lines in this file for tests.

Thanks for every answers and help.

```
#hibernate.connection.driver_class = org.postgresql.Driver
#hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dummydb
#hibernate.connection.username = postgres
#hibernate.connection.password = postgres
#hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL91Dialect

hibernate.connection.driver_class = org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:hsqldb:mem:dummydb
hibernate.connection.username = user
hibernate.connection.password = password
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect

hibernate.show_sql=true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Spring profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) to separet production and test envirionments.

In your case you need to create 2 property files: `application.property` and `application-test.property`. First must contains you production env, Second envirionments for tests.

Then you need to chouse `test` profile when unit tests are executed. Just add `@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")` to your test classes.

Comment: Why would you use hibernate property files for a Spring Boot application. You can configure the hibernate properties directly in the application.properties file instead. Or if you using yaml then in the application.yml file. [Configure JPA Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-configure-jpa-properties)